# Ubuntu Server reviving bad route at reboot

Tags: networking, server, routing

I recently moved an Ubuntu 18.04.5 server from one network (192.168.101.X) to a new network (192.168.1.X).  The server (and all network devices) are addressed by DHCP, issued by an Edgerouter Lite.  Everything works great, except that whenever I reboot the server it seems to revive an old route that blocks all outbound connectivity.

After each reboot, I see this in ip route, where 192.168.1.236 is the machine's current IP:

```
default via 192.168.101.1 dev enp3s0 src 192.168.1.236 metric 202
```

This causes all outbound traffic from the machine to fail.

If I run `netplan apply` it replaces that with the correct default route:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.236 metric 100
```

and everything works correctly immediately.

Here is my `cat 50-cloud-init.yaml`

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        enp3s0:
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2
```

Since the server is running netplan, there is no /etc/network/interfaces.
I don't think it's a DHCP server issue, since all other devices on the network are doing fine.
I don't believe I ever configured any static IP or gateway on this device, but maybe I did, and I can't find it?  Where else besides netplan do I need to be looking for this?

I'd rather not setup a static route, but I can if that's the only solution.  Right now anything I add with `ip route add` gets overwritten at boot.